# NextJS 'fetch' returning error or null, browser returns expected response

Tags: next.js, prisma, app-router

`NextJS` version 13.4.10

I'm trying to build routes to wrap CRUD against `Prisma` using more or less the same pattern I would use in REST contexts for other languages, using the `App Router`, but I'm encountering a behavior that I don't understand.

```js
// path: /app/api/posts/[postId]/route.ts
export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params }: { params: {postId: string}}) {
    try {
        const postId = parseInt(params.postId, 10)
        const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: postId,
            },
        });
        console.log("Debug:", post)
        return NextResponse.json(post);
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ "message": "error" });
    }
}
```

This works just fine in the browser. I get a JSON-response with the expected values, a response that I have manually double-checked to come from the db.

But when I try to `fetch` it on a page, it's not so smooth anymore:

```js
export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { projectId: number } }) {

  const projectIdSTR = params.projectId;
  const pid = parseInt(projectIdSTR.toString(), 10);

  let url: string = `/api/posts/${params.pid}`
  console.log("url:", url)

  try {
    const postRes = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })

    const post = await postRes.json()
    console.log(post);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({"Error occurred": error});
  }
```

1. The first thing to note is the URL, which as far as I can tell, is the advised method of doing this in the newest iteration of App Router - relative pathing for server-side resources. But in combination with this error and stack trace, I don't know what to make of it:

```
  'Error occurred': TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/posts/5
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11) {
    [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
        at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
        at new URL (node:internal/url:560:13)
        at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7041:25)
        at fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10598:25)
        at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11455:18)
        at fetch (node:internal/process/pre_execution:230:25)
        at doOriginalFetch (E:\My Documents\NextJS\...\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\patch-fetch.js:273:24)
        [...]
```

It's worth noting that I can use relative paths elsewhere, but in those cases it is to resources that don't use a path parameter. `/api/posts` for example works without problem.

This code works perfectly for example:

```js
      const mockPost: Post =
        {
          title: data.placeholder,
          content: data.address,
          name: user.username,
          url: user.email,
        };

      const res = await fetch('/api/posts', { 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(mockPost),
      });
```

2. Changing the URL of the problematic code to `http://localhost:3000/` + the relative path gets rid of the displayed error, but the logging statements in the route do not get called, `fetch` reports a status of 401 and the `.json()` of the response returns as `null`. So obviously something is still gone awry.
3. As noted earlier, visiting `http://localhost:3000/` etc. results in a perfect JSON response in the browser:
   [image]

Am I completely in the dark about how to combine the REST pattern for App Router with Prisma, or what is going on here?

Comment: You can call `prisma` directly in your `Page` component (or make a wrapper function if you reuse in multiple places), you don't need to make a route for it.

Comment: @Danila Thanks. But let's say I'm trying to write an actual API endpoint, am I not able to fetch data from `prisma` when I respond to incoming `GET` requests? Or does this mean that I have to make a `Page` component for API endpoints?

Comment: Right now you are trying to fetch data on the server side (Page component) from your own server through HTTP request (api route). It does not makes much sense to do it like that, you can just call your db directly from the Page. But if you need real api endpoint to use from the client side then what you have (api route) will work fine, you can test it by adding a fetch call inside of `useEffect` for example.

Comment: @Danila So in essence, would you say that it's only inside a server component (or context) that the GET route as listed above wouldn't work? That seems odd to me when the POST does work in the same scenario, and I would be curious as to any insight to the logic behind this.